# ResizeObserver loop completed with undelivered notifications

Tags: webpack, vuejs3, quasar

I am getting this error always when I remove or add component to page with page changes. For these code, error accuses when value of showUserToolBar is changed.

I tried to change value of showUserToolBar with setTimeout, but it is not worked. Also, I tried to remove or add component with click event, but it also not worked. Moreover, I can't capture this error with errorCaptured

Uncaught runtime errors:

```
ERROR
ResizeObserver loop completed with undelivered notifications.
    at handleError (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/webpack-devserver/client/overlay.js:252:58)
    at eval (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/webpack-dev-server/client/overlay.js:271:7)
```

```xml
<q-header reveal height-hint="107" class="bg-white ctitle">
    <q-toolbar class="text-center">
      <q-toolbar-title style="padding-top: 8px;">
        <funo-text-icon style="height: 30px;" />
      </q-toolbar-title>
    </q-toolbar>
    <template v-if="showUserToolBar">
      <q-toolbar class="text-center ctitle fw600 fs16 lh20" style="padding: 0 16px; border-bottom: 1px solid #E8E8E8;">
        <div class="row flex-center" style="gap:12px">
          <user-avatar :photo-url="userData?.general.photoUrl" />
          Merhaba {{ userData?.general.name }}
        </div>
        <div style="flex-grow: 1; flex-shrink: 1;" />
        <div class="row flex-center" style="gap:8px">
          <q-icon size="37px">
            <alert-icon />
          </q-icon>
          <q-icon size="37px">
            <message-icon />
          </q-icon>
        </div>
      </q-toolbar>
    </template>
  </q-header>
```

```js
computed(){
    showUserToolBar() {
      const excludedPathNames = ["UserProfileView", "CalendarView", "MapView"]
      if (!this.$route.name) return true
      if (excludedPathNames.indexOf(this.$route.name.toString()) != -1) return false
      return true
    }
}
```

```json
{
  "scripts": {
    "serve": "vue-cli-service serve",
    "build": "vue-cli-service build",
    "lint": "vue-cli-service lint"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@capacitor-firebase/authentication": "^5.1.0",
    "@capacitor/android": "^5.3.0",
    "@capacitor/core": "^5.2.3",
    "@capacitor/dialog": "^5.0.6",
    "@capacitor/ios": "^5.3.0",
    "@capacitor/preferences": "^5.0.6",
    "@quasar/extras": "^1.0.0",
    "core-js": "^3.8.3",
    "firebase": "10.3.0",
    "ol": "^7.5.1",
    "pinia": "^2.1.6",
    "quasar": "^2.0.0",
    "vue": "^3.2.13",
    "vue-router": "^4.0.3"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@capacitor/cli": "^5.2.3",
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^5.4.0",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^5.4.0",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-babel": "~5.0.0",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-eslint": "~5.0.0",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-router": "~5.0.0",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-typescript": "~5.0.0",
    "@vue/cli-service": "~5.0.0",
    "@vue/eslint-config-typescript": "^9.1.0",
    "eslint": "^7.32.0",
    "eslint-plugin-vue": "^8.0.3",
    "sass": "1.32.12",
    "sass-loader": "^12.0.0",
    "typescript": "~4.5.5",
    "vue-cli-plugin-quasar": "~5.0.2"
  }
}
```

Also, I can capture the error with `window.onerror` and when page is reloaded error does not occur.

```js
 mounted() {
    window.onerror = function () {
      window.location.reload()
    };
  }
```

Comment: I have the same issue with vuejs 3 + quasar templates, it appears when I click inside a q-input. 
Tried `npm update` it updated a lot of packages but still the error appears

Comment: https://github.com/juggle/resize-observer/blob/master/README.md#resize-loop-detection
This error message is the feature of webpack. This won't appears in built version of app.

Comment: Here is the solution: https://github.com/vuejs/vue-cli/issues/7431#issuecomment-1821173102